# Error trying to insert with PDO: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting this error:
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => )

```
$arr = array();
    $values = "";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO avisos(nombre ";
    $values.=":nombre";
    $arr[] = "nombre => $nombre";

    if($plataforma!=""){
        $sql .= ", idPlataforma";
        $values.=", :idPlataforma";
        $arr[] = "idPlataforma => $plataforma";
    }
    if(idCompania!=""){
        $sql .= ", idCompania";
        $values.=", :idCompania";
        $arr[] = "idCompania => $compania";
    }
    if($fondo!=""){
        $sql .= ", idFondo";
        $values.=", :idFondo";
        $arr[] = "idFondo => $fondo";
    }
    if($remitente != ''){
        $sql .= ", idRemitente";
        $values.=", :idRemitente";
        $arr[] = "idRemitente => $remitente";
    }
    $sql.= ") VALUES ($values);";

    $stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 

    if ($stmt->execute($arr)){
        echo "OK";
    }
```

I can´t see where I´m failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array you send to `execute()` needs to have key-value pairs where the keys are the placeholders and the values are the values you want to insert.

So instead of:

```
$arr[] = "nombre => $nombre";
```

You need:

```
$arr[':nombre'] = $nombre;
```

or:

```
$arr['nombre'] = $nombre;
```

etc.